# The server tag is not well formed. in asp.net using another sql result in repeater

Tags: asp.net

Parser Error Message: **The server tag is not well formed.**
Source Error:

```
Line 27:  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PCName") %>' /> 
Line 28:  </li>
Line 29:  <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
Line 30:  DataFile="~/Database/PDetail.mdb" 
Line 31:  SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [PBName] FROM [PDETAIL] WHERE PCName= <%# Eval("PCName")%> ">
```

Comment: What line is your actual error on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SelectCommand='SELECT DISTINCT [PBName] FROM [PDETAIL] WHERE PCName= <%# Eval("PCName")%> '>
```

Surround the SelectCommand with `''` and not with `""`

Comment: That is not true.  It can be double quotes.

Comment: actually the OP used this with Label1

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your closing slash:

```
.... WHERE PCName= <%# Eval("PCName")%> " />
```

Comment: doesnt that tag continue onto line 31?

Comment: @RobertDondo That is line 31.

Comment: <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/Database/PDetail.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [PBName] FROM [PDETAIL] WHERE PCName= <%# Eval("PCName")%> ">
</asp:AccessDataSource>

Comment: Well that's a bit of a different story now, isn't it.